# How to use visual studio code LaTex Workshop with xelatex

Tags: xetex, visual-studio-code

I want to compile a tex document using xelatex in [LaTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) extension in visual studio code. How can I change compiler from default one to xetex? I put my current setting.json file bellow.

```
{
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [

        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "lualatexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-lualatex",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk_rconly",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "bibtex",
            "command": "bibtex",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "rnw2tex",
            "command": "Rscript",
            "args": [
                "-e",
                "knitr::opts_knit$set(concordance = TRUE); knitr::knit('%DOCFILE_EXT%')"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "jnw2tex",
            "command": "julia",
            "args": [
                "-e",
                "using Weave; weave(\"%DOC_EXT%\", doctype=\"tex\")"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "jnw2texmintex",
            "command": "julia",
            "args": [
                "-e",
                "using Weave; weave(\"%DOC_EXT%\", doctype=\"texminted\")"
            ],
            "env": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe all you were looking for was:

```
{
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "name of recipe",
}
```

which sets the default build recipe for LaTeX-Workshop. But I came across this question when trying to figure out how to build my file with xelatex, which I have now figured out:

I use latexmk with -xelatex option, which I have installed on Windows via MiKTeX. I used the command line in my project folder to find what arguments got me the result I wanted. In my case, the following did the trick:

```
D:\path\to\project>latexmk -xelatex -outdir=out file.tex
```

Since this result is usually fixed for a certain project, I just override tools and recipes in

*D:\path\to\project\.vscode\settings.json*:

```
{
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "latexmk (xelatex)",
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "xelatexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-xelatex",
                "-outdir=out",
                "file.tex"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk (xelatex)",
            "tools": [
                "xelatexmk"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have chosen to just hard-code my root file and output directory in the tool, but you can also use [Placeholders](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#placeholders).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: A `latexmk (xelatex)` recipe and `xelatexmk` tool are now built into the LaTeX-Workshop extension (https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/commit/49ca779da64a2e6bdd41f4f1e324155fd6d1b86f)

Answer (score 6):

### Method 1

Here is how to add using placeholders without specifying `file.tex`, following @mbockstael 's answer. Personally I like `%DOCFILE%` the most, but using something like `"%DOC%.tex"` is fine too.

Either in your global `settings.json` or the one in your workspace setting under `.vscode` directory, first add the tools,

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "xelatexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-xelatex",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
]
```

Then, in the recipes, just add `xelatexmk`

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk ",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex × 2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "bibtex",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
        // let us suppose the first two recipes are Latexmk vanilla and 
        // pdflatex twice for bibtex
        {
            "name": "latexmk (xelatex)",
            "tools": [
                "xelatexmk"
            ]
        },
]
```

The first method has a drawback. We have to set the LatexWorkshop's recipe to be `lastUsed`,

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "lastUsed",
```

Otherwise, the next time you want to build the same file, you have to go the extension menu to choose the `xelatexmk` one. So we have a better option 2 as follows.

---

### Method 2

A better option would be simply using the [magic comments](https://www.texdev.net/2011/03/24/texworks-magic-comments/), i.e., simply adding

```latex
% !TeX program = xelatex
```

on top of the file shall do the trick when invoking `latexmk`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  latexmk does not appear to use these comments.

Comment: @polyglot You have to enable it first, see: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/3027

Answer (score 4):

Here's the simplified version of @wolfrevo's answer. Setting the default recipe from the LaTeX VS Code extension is enough to set `xelatex`. There's no need to define `xelatex` from VS Code settings again since all the options exist. All we have to do is select the one we want to use.

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "latexmk (xelatex)",
```

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code extension LaTex Workshop there are three interrelated settings you'll need to set:

1. `latex-workshop.latex.tools`
2. `latex-workshop.latex.recipes` (which refers to one of the `latex-workshop.latex.tools`)
3. `latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default` (which refers to one of the `latex-workshop.latex.recipes`)

`LaTeX Workshop` will add for you:

- a list of "tools" if you go to Settings and search for `latex-workshop.latex.tools` and click "Edit in settings.json". One of them is `xelatexmk` (which calls `latexmk -xelatex ...`):

  ```json
  "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
      ...
      {
          "name": "xelatexmk",
          "command": "latexmk",
          "args": [
              "-synctex=1",
              "-interaction=nonstopmode",
              "-file-line-error",
              "-xelatex",
              "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
              "%DOC%"
          ],
          "env": {}
      },
      ...
  ],
  ```
- a list of "recipes" if you go to Settings and search for `latex-workshop.latex.recipes` and click "Edit in settings.json". One of them is `latexmk (xelatex)` (which refers to the above mentioned tool name`xelatexmk`):

  ```json
  "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
      ...
      {
          "name": "latexmk (xelatex)",
          "tools": [
              "xelatexmk"
          ]
      },
      ...
  ],
  ```

Then you'll need to set the default recipe.

Go to Settings and search for `latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default` and enter the above mentioned recipe name `latexmk (xelatex)`. Or add it to your settings.json:

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "latexmk (xelatex)",
```

Further you could (a) configure the arguments and environment passed to your tool and/or (b) remove all other tools and recipes if you don't need them.

**Important:** Make sure you save your settings.json file before make changes in the settings dialogs. Otherwise you'll overwrite them when you save the settings.json!